# Can't See NFT on OpenSea Testnet

Tags: solidity, contract-development, nft, testnets, opensea

I just deployed my contract on rinkeby and minted one nft, but I can't see the nft information on OpenSea testnet. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that I needed to put `.json` at the end of the Token URI.

Also, I used this debbuger to validate the metadata:
https://api.opensea.io/asset/<your_contract_address>/<your_token_id>/validate/